# Calling function to work

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm new to JavaScript and I need to use the string method all in one html page. I need to make sure user input the data, but I can't get my function calling to work. Any idea? I finished all of it, but just to make sure that one button submit can validate all string method function perfectly.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset ="utf-8"/>
        <h1> Try 1</h1>
      <p>Please enter all the field below.</p>
    </head>
      <body>
        <form id="myForm">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>String Methods</legend>

              <p>Using concat()</p>
              <input type="text" id="word1" size="25" placeholder="Enter first word/sentences."></br>
              <input type="text" id="word2" size="25" placeholder="Enter second word/sentences."></br></br>

              <p>Using substr()</p>
              <input type="text" id="subtr" size="25" placeholder="Please enter word/sentences."></br></br>

              <p>Using lastIndexOf()</p>
              <input type="text" id="lastindex" size="25" placeholder="Please enter word/sentences."></br>
              <input type="text" id="srch" size="25" placeholder="Word that you want to search."></br></br>

              <p>Using toLowerCase()</p>
              <input type="text" id="lcase" size="35" placeholder="Please enter Uppercase word/sentences."></br></br>

              <p>Using toUpperCase()</p>
              <input type="text" id="ucase" size="35" placeholder="Please enter Lowercase word/sentences."></br></br>

              <p>Using match()</p>
              <input type="text" id="match" size="25" placeholder="Please enter word/sentences."></br>
              <input type="text" id="match1" size="25" placeholder="Words that you want to find match."></br></br>

              <p>Using replace()</p>
              <p id="phrase"><i>The voice in my head shouts out through the world like a breath.</i></p>
              <input type="text" id="replce" size="35" placeholder="Word you want to change in sentence above."></br>
              <input type="text" id="replce2" size="25" placeholder="Word you want to change with."></br></br>

              <p>Using split()</p>
              <input type="text" id="splt" size="25" placeholder="Please enter word/sentences."></br></br>

              <p>Using charCodeAt()</p>
              <input type="text" id="cca" size="25" placeholder="Please enter word/sentences."></br></br>

              <p>Using slice()</p>
              <input type="text" id="slce" size="25" placeholder="Please enter word/sentences."></br></br>

              <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="validateEverything()">
          </fieldset>

          </form>
          <div id="answers"></div>
          </body>
         </html>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
   <script>
          function validateEverything(){
            var wo1 = document.getElementById("word1").value;
            var wo2 = document.getElementById("word2").value;

            var sub = document.getElementById("subtr").value;

            var lin = document.getElementById("lastindex").value;
            var sea = document.getElementById("srch").value;

            var lca = document.getElementById("lcase").value;
            var uca = document.getElementById("ucase").value;

            var mat = document.getElementById("match").value;
            var ma1 = document.getElementById("match1").value;

            var phr = document.getElementById("phrase").value;
            var rep = document.getElementById("replce").value;
            var re1 = document.getElementById("replce1").value;

            var ph1 = document.getElementById("phrase1").value;
            var spl = document.getElementById("splt").value;

            var cha = document.getElementById("cca").value;

            var slc = document.getElementById("slce").value;

            var ans = document.getElementById("answers");

            //Concat
            var con = wo1.concat(" "+wo2);

            //Subtr
            var subr = sub.substring(1, 7);

            //lastindexof
            var n = lin.lastIndexOf(sea);

            //toLowerCase
            var lc = lca.toLowerCase();

            //toUpperCase
            var uc = uca.toUpperCase();

            //match
            var mc = mat.match(ma1);

            //replace
            var rp = phr.replace(replce, replce1);

            //split
            var sp = sp1.split(" ")

            //charCodeAt
            var cc = cha.charCodeAt(0);

            //slice
            var sl = slc.slice(1, 5);

            show();
          }

          function show(){
            ans.innerHTML = answersHTML();
          }
            //answers
            function answersHTML(){
            var ans = document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML;
            document.write(con);
            document.write(subr);
            document.write(n);
            document.write(lc);
            document.write(uc);
            document.write(mc);
            document.write(rp);
            document.write(sp);
            document.write(cc);
            document.write(sl);

          }
        </script>
```

Comment: where are you stuck? any errors on the console?

Comment: You need to write validation functions in `$(function() { .. validation code ... })` or in document ready function

Comment: @Apb jQuery is not in the tag. Only javascript

Comment: Check by changing `Submit` button to `input type button`.

Comment: make input button type submit  to button 
or return false  on  your method

Comment: For javascript, you can use self executable function as `(function() { // your page initialization code here// the DOM will be available here })();`

Comment: In your last function, none of the variables are defined. I think you may want to study about scopes http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your snippet.In some case there is no DOM element present but still you are doing document.getElementById();

Also how `answerHTML` will know about `con,sub,....` ? They are local to `validateEverything` function & you are not passing it to `answerHTML` function

You are using `input type = "submit"`. You need to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop submission. You are not submitting anything. Rather use `input type = "button"`

There is also no use of `show()` function

Everytime you are using `document.write`, so it will delete anything which is previously written. Instead string `concatenation` and `innerHTML` will be fine.
Here is a working snippet with minimum code.

**JS**

```
function validateEverything(event){
          event.preventDefault();
            var wo1 = document.getElementById("word1").value;
            var wo2 = document.getElementById("word2").value;
            var sub = document.getElementById("subtr").value;
            var ans = document.getElementById("answers");
            //Concat
            var con = wo1.concat(" "+wo2);
            //Subtr
            var subr = sub.substring(1, 7);

      ans.innerHTML = con+" "+subr;
          }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="validateEverything(event)">
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/jahm7a70/2/)